# Cloudera spark connection from local machine

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, cloudera, cloudera-cdh

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

sparkdriver=SparkSession.builder.master("spark://<cloudera-ip-address>:7077").appName("mytryapp").getOrCreate()
sparkdriver
```

I'm trying to connect cloudera spark master node from local windows machine python code using pyspark and i'm getting the following error

```
Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call la

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling None.org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.
: java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManagerMaster.registerBlockManager(BlockManagerMaster.scala:64)
at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.initialize(BlockManager.scala:248)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:510)
at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.<init>(JavaSparkContext.scala:58)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at 
sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:247)
at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:238)
at py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.invokeConstructor(ConstructorCommand.java:80)
at py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.execute(ConstructorCommand.java:69)
at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I'm unable to find what went wrong while im connecting to cloudera's spark master. Any kind of help is appreciated.

Thank You

Comment: Can you point some Cloudera documentation about connecting to their clusters? Are you running from a local machine? Are you sure you have access to their 7077 port?

Comment: spark master is at url **spark://<cloudera-ip-address>:7077**  and is accessable according to the documentation. Im using QuickStart 5.13 cloudera   [https://docs.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-13-x/topics/cdh_ig_ports_cdh5.html

Comment: Have you configured and started Spark standalone (master, worker, SHS)? By default, Cloudera supports `master("yarn")`.

Comment: yes, I have configured Spark Standalone master

Comment: is the interactive shell working for you? terminal -> pyspark